# How to store list items after refresh or exit and revisiting the page without deleting the items?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a basic and unstyled to-do list using Javascript. I want the browser to remember the list items when I refresh the page or when I exit the page and revisit it.

I also want the user to be able to click an "X" or something to delete the list item from the browser's memory and to forget it.

Here's my code:

#### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>My TO-DOs</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>My Todos</h1>

        <form>
            <label>Add an item:</label>
            <input type="text">

            <button type="submit">ADD</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <ul id="itemList"></ul>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const input = document.querySelector('input');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if (input.value === '' || input.value === null) {
        alert('You cannot add a blank item.');
    } else{
    const listItem = document.createElement('li');
    const listItemText = document.createTextNode(input.value);
    listItem.appendChild(listItemText);
    

    const listElement = document.getElementById('itemList');
    listElement.appendChild(listItem)

    // Clear the input after adding an item
    input.value = '';
    input.focus();
}});
```

##### Here is a code snippet:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const input = document.querySelector('input');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if (input.value === '' || input.value === null) {
        alert('You cannot add a blank item.');
    } else{
    const listItem = document.createElement('li');
    const listItemText = document.createTextNode(input.value);
    listItem.appendChild(listItemText);
    

    const listElement = document.getElementById('itemList');
    listElement.appendChild(listItem)

    // Clear the input after adding an item
    input.value = '';
    input.focus();
}});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>My TO-DOs</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>My Todos</h1>

        <form>
            <label>Add an item:</label>
            <input type="text">

            <button type="submit">ADD</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <ul id="itemList"></ul>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Put them in an array and save the array as JSON in `localStorage`.

Comment: look into localStorage.getItem, localStorage.setItem, JSON.parse, and JSON.stringify.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage